# Как получить то, что было задано с define в lua FFI?

Tags: lua

Многие функции системного программирования в linux работают с флагами (например, `O_NONBLOCK`). Но эти флаги же надо ещё и получить! Насколько я понимаю, флаги в заголовочных файлах определены при помощи `#define`. Традиционное нечто вроде `ffi.C.O_NONBLOCK` выдаёт ошибку, это не функция и не глобальная переменная! При этом файл заголовков подгружен при помощи библиотеки `lcpp`. И как же получить эти самые `define`'ы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надо использовать не `ffi.C.` а `ffi.lcpp_defs.`.

**Пример 1**

Файл test1.lua:

```lua
local lcpp = require("lcpp")
local ffi = require("ffi")

ffi.cdef([[
    #define MAX_SIZE 100
    typedef struct {
        int data[MAX_SIZE];
    } test_t;
]])

print("MAX_SIZE = " .. ffi.lcpp_defs.MAX_SIZE)
```

Результат работы:

> `MAX_SIZE = 100`

**Пример 2**

Файл test2.lua:

```lua
local lcpp = require("lcpp")
local ffi = require("ffi")

ffi.cdef("#include \"test.h\"")

print("FREQUENCY_MHZ = " .. ffi.lcpp_defs.FREQUENCY_MHZ)
print("FREQUENCY_KHZ = " .. ffi.lcpp_defs.FREQUENCY_KHZ)
print("_PACKED_ = " .. ffi.lcpp_defs._PACKED_)
```

Файл test.h:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#define FREQUENCY_MHZ 2
#define FREQUENCY_KHZ (FREQUENCY_MHZ * 1000)

#define _PACKED_ __attribute__((packed))

#endif // TEST_H
```

Результат работы:

> ```
> FREQUENCY_MHZ = 2
> FREQUENCY_KHZ = (FREQUENCY_MHZ * 1000)
> _PACKED_ = __attribute__((packed))
> ```

Всё в общем-то работает, но из второго примера видно, что полного препроцессинга `define`'ов не происходит. На самом деле тут всё не так плохо.

**Пример 3**

Файл test3.lua:

```lua
local ffi = require("ffi")
local lcpp = require("lcpp")

local data, state = lcpp.compile([[
    #define ROW_CNT 0x0F
    #define COL_CNT 0x0A
    #define DATA_CNT (ROW_CNT * COL_CNT)
    int data[DATA_CNT];
]])
local data_type = ffi.typeof(data)

print("data = " .. data)
print("ROW_CNT = " .. state.defines.ROW_CNT)
print("COL_CNT = " .. state.defines.COL_CNT)
print("DATA_CNT = " .. state.defines.DATA_CNT)
print("typeof(data) = " .. tostring(data_type))
```

Результат работы:

> ```
> data = int data[(15*10)];
> ROW_CNT = 0x0F
> COL_CNT = 0x0A
> DATA_CNT = (ROW_CNT * COL_CNT)
> typeof(data) = ctype<int[150]>
> ```

Как видно из этого примера, размерность массива вычислена правильно (150 элементов).